# Speed test of a web page : how to get the theoretical loading speed

Tags: performance, browser, html, theory, pagespeed

There are many tools online to measure the speed of a web page.
They provide data such as the loading time of a page.
This loading time depends on the number of files downloaded at the same time and the connection speed (and many other things such as the network state, the content providers, so on).

However, because it is based on the speed of the connection, we don't have the theoretical loading time.
A browser downloads many resources at the same time within a certain limit (5 resource at the same time). So it is optimized to load the resources faster.
If we could set the speed connection to a fixed amount, the loading page of a page would "never" change.

So does anyone know a tool which computes this theoretical loading time of a web page ?

I'd like to get this kind of results :
Theoretical loading time : 56 * t
With t equals the amount of time to download 1kb of data.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "theoretical loading time"? Such a formula would have a huge number of variables (Bandwidth, Round-Trip Time, Processor speed, Antenna Wakeup Time, Load on Server, Packet Loss, Whether TCP Connections Are Already Open, ...) which ones would you put into your theoretical calculation?

And what is the problem you are trying to solve? If you just want a more objective measure of site speed, you can use a tester like http://www.webpagetest.org/ which allows you to choose the network speed and then run many tests to find the distribution of load times.

Note also, that there is not even agreement on when a page is finished loading! Most people measure time until onload handler is called, but that can easily be sped up by prematurely reaching onload and then doing the actual loading of resources with JS afterwards. Waiting until all resources are loaded could also be a bad measure, because many modern pages will continually be updating themselves and loading new resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these three tools: SpeedPage, DevTools, and WebPageTest. Read more at: [TEST YOUR WEBSITE'S LOADING TIME / MOBILE SITE LOADING SPEED](http://webdev-coders-tips.blogspot.com/2015/10/test-yur-website-load-time-mobile-site.html) blog post.